# JavaScript code to Class Diagram

Tags: javascript, scripting, uml, class-diagram

I am looking for a tool that can generate class diagram from JavaScript code. Similar to the ones for C++ and Java. Is there any?

Comment: For `Atlassian Confluence` there's [draw.io](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.mxgraph.confluence.plugins.diagramly/cloud/overview)

Answer (score 13):

If you are using node.js, i made a module that generate a class diagram for javascript/node/html/css. Its called wavi. For javascript, function and variable are recognized.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/wavi

[image: Diagram generated by wavi]

Comment: Is it configurable? For example I don't want variables to be visible. I didn't find any info about this. Thanks!

Comment: @Serob_b Did you find out whether it is configurable to hide variables?

Comment: I am finding that [wavi isn't creating diagrams of a Cordova project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464056/how-to-troubleshoot-why-wavi-is-finding-synatx-errors-in-a-cordova-project-that).

Comment: @Galen Eventually I couldn't find any info on this. It seems it is not configurable.

Comment: @Serob_b Sorry to hear that! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Galen I haven't used this for 3 years, so maybe things have changed and you can try to find out something from the other places and not rely only on my answer ;)