# Tool to convert JavaScript file to Class Diagram

Tags: javascript, class-diagram

I am looking for any tool that can convert JavaScript file to Class Diagram.

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/943212/1048572. Please search before asking.

Comment: I saw that already. It is for eclipse. It is been asked 5 years ago so.

Comment: Couldn't find anything other then [this](http://gaertner-network.de/jsuml/), but you need eclipse for it to work. But eclipse is free so..

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jsuml](http://jsuml.sourceforge.net/):

> JS/UML is a plugin for the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) that creates UML models and
>   diagrams from JavaScript code.
>
> **What does JS/UML do?**
>
> 1. Imports JavaScript that is written in the [styles](http://jsuml.sourceforge.net/js-filters.html) of JSDoc or YUI
> 2. Creates a UML model of the parsed JavaScript code which can be
>      viewed using the Eclipse UML2 model editor
> 3. Creates UML diagrams that can be editing using the diagram editors
>      from Eclipse's [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/) project
> 4. Generates documentation for the modeled API using provided templates
>      or custom templates [you design](http://jsuml.sourceforge.net/doc-generator.html)
>
> **What is next at JS/UML?**
>
> 1. Stub Generation - New templates to create javascript stubs from
>      existing UML diagrams
> 2. Services Generation - New templates to create services based on
>      those from [zoe-express](https://github.com/chubbz327/zoe-express)
> 3. Using JS/UML
>
> You can download JS/UML [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsuml/files/). Then please read the [Install](http://jsuml.sourceforge.net/install.html) and
>   [Quick Start](http://jsuml.sourceforge.net/quick-start.html) guides.